# Parsing JSON content with Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON file which stores geocode_output

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "277",
               "short_name" : "277",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bedford Avenue",
               "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings County",
               "short_name" : "Kings County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "11211",
               "short_name" : "11211",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ]
       }
```

I am trying to return the value in the value `"11211"` from the `"long_name"` in the `"postal_code"` type field at the bottom of the file.

How should I parse it and return the value as a string?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look at JSONPath, dpath, and KVC, three different APIs for searching JSON-style nested structures with a nice path syntax, which all have Python modules on PyPI.

Comment: If not, just loop. Break it down step by step, and all the parts are easy. `results = d['results']`, then `for result in results:`, then `components = result['address_components']`, then `for component in components:`, then you can do things like `if 'postal_code' in component['types']:`.

Comment: @abarnert When I try to break down the parts step by step I get the following error  "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str." Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over your JSON.

**Ex:**

```
for address in data["results"]:
    for i in address["address_components"]:
        if i["long_name"] == "11211":
            print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
{'long_name': '11211', 'types': ['postal_code'], 'short_name': '11211'}
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. When I run that I get the following error message "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str." Any idea why?